# MVC Url Routing For custom url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to pass url link like

```
http://localhost:24873/Jobs/[companyname]
or
http://localhost:24873/[companyname]/Jobs/ (Preferred)
```

I tried below routing in global aspx file and created controller named Jobs and Index action result with Jobs folder but not working.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
             "JobList", // Route name
             "Jobs/{companyname}",
              new
              {
                  controller = "Jobs",
                  action = "Index",
                  companyname = string.Empty
              }
          );
```

And my controller:

```
public partial class JobsController : Controller 
{ 
    public ActionResult Index() 
    { 
          JobsListModel model = new JobsListModel(); 
          return View(model); 
    } 
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? It's not executing the controller method? It's not matching the route? It's giving an error message?  Have you tried Phil Haack's [route tester](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) on it?

Comment: it is giving resource cannot be found page. Can you please correct me for routing? to match and work like my example url

Comment: Did you add this route as the first MapRoute entry in Global.asax file?

Comment: great.. I added route as the first MapRoute entry in Global.asax file and its working now... Can you please tell me reason for it that why I need to make that as first map route entry?

Comment: @Keyur: Apparently it's matching one of your other routes. The other route it is matching is apparently broken (it doesn't have a corresponding controller method).

Comment: ok robert, Thanks getting it. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add this route as the first entry in global.asax, otherwise the request will be routed to the default route (or route before it)

[Source](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)

Comment: Thanks but still getting little confused about its ordering. As I am also adding it after default root. Do you mean that adding it as first to check custom routes first.

Comment: @Keyur - Yes, you should add this custom route first, and add the default route after.  The request will first try to use your custom route.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the previous answer, if you want your preferred route of `http://localhost:24873/[companyname]/Jobs/` to work, add this route, again before your default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "JobList", // Route name
  "{companyname}/Jobs",
  new
  {
     controller = "Jobs",
     action = "Index",
     companyname = string.Empty
  }
);
```

Comment: how/where is the company name being added to the url?

Comment: it would be passed through the url when the page was requested, that's what the {companyname} in the route definition suggests, the string.Empty, simply gives a default value

Answer (score 0):

Your jobs controller needs an index action with a named parameter of companyname like such:

```
public ActionResult Index(string companyname) 
{ 
      //Do some checking on the name
      JobsListModel model = new JobsListModel(); 
      return View(model); 
}
```

You will probably still need the empty action as well:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
    return Index(string.Empty);
}
```

Oh, missed this.  Like the guy ahead of me said to get your other url to work do this: (http://localhost:24873/[companyname]/Jobs/)

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "JobList", // Route name
  "{companyname}/Jobs",
  new
  {
     controller = "Jobs",
     action = "Index",
     companyname = string.Empty
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
//Default url

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

//others url rewriting you want

RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(null, "Jobs/{companyname}", new { controller = "Jobs", action = "Index" });
```