# adding custom view name in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an application in .net mvc4 that is based on business promotion and sales store.

User on this web application would be able to use product and access his/her personal business page also, that page can be promoted in future.

So I added one controller- `Mypanel` and a view of user's personal or professional business page `_Mypanel`.

Now the url access to this page is `Bizcopter.com/Mypanel/_Mypanel`

**I want a custom user defined page name-**

i.e. If a business name is - BookStore
Then I want to add a view in this same controller with the name of `BookStore`, So URL of personal business page would be-

`Bizcopter.com/Mypanel/BookStore/` and this business holder can promote his business page with this URL.

Let me know if these are possible-

1. Replacing the view's name of user's choice
2. Add a view from client side in this same controller

I don't have any idea how to make it happen so don't have any trying code.

Site URL- http://bizcopter.com/Mypanel/_Mypanel

Comment: You will need to define a custom route to handle this URL template which will pass "BookStore" as a parameter to a controller function which will then redirect the user to the relevant page.

Comment: This SO question might give you some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706183/mvc-url-routing-for-custom-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate view and controller action for each business.

I would create a controller and view called `MyPanel`. The controller takes a parameter called something like `businessName` that will load data related to the parameter.

Comment: That would still be this URL - `bizcopter.com/Mypanel/Mypanel/` not exactly the view's name with business name. Nobody would show interest in promoting my defined URL. I don't have any problem in loading data btw :)

Comment: @Manoz you can customize the route the way you want it. Take a look at this -> http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: @Manoz, no it wouldn't. The URL would be bizcopter.com/Mypanel/[buinsessName]. Although with routing you are not constrained to any format - it's very flexible.

Comment: yes man! I could access page without any controller and action name also. Great

Answer (score 2):

By default you'll have a route in your AppStart/RouteConfig.cs which may look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The default URL structure might look something similar to: `http://localhost:{PortNumber}/{Controller}/{Action}`

Where we can attribute the following:

```
Controller = Home

Action = Index
```

Now if you want something similar to how you have it, you'd want something along the lines of:

```
http://testing.com/Fruits/Apples

Controller = Fruits

Action = Apples
```

By default, a URL pattern will match any URL that has the correct number of segments, in this case {controller}/{action}

Overall you should just need the MyPanel controller, and a controller taking a parameter of string which loads the correct Object/Model into the view.

Source: Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 - Adam Freeman

Answer (score 1):

As the others said you can add a new route.Consider this code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyCustomRoute",
            url: "MyPanel/{name}"
            defaults: new  { controller = "MyPanel", action = "MyAction", name="" }
        );
```

In this route if user type this URL:

```
Bizcopter.com/Mypanel/
```

Then it goes to your `MyAction` in your `MyPanel Controller` by default.Actually it will always go to `MyAction`, and in your MyAction, you must take the `name` parameter and redirect to user to the Relevant Action like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() 
{
    var name = RouteDate.Values["name"];

    // check the name and redirect user to another action if it necessary

    if(name == "BookStore") return RedirectToAction("BookStore","Mypanel");
}
```